# jQuery add additional value to next column in every row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add more values to my row, 
but all the columns show same number.

I am trying to work with:

```
$this.parent().next().children('.output-value2').val((scorenetto).toFixed(2));
```

but it won't work.
Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QjwdR/15/

the additional column  "Price2 for Count in €" not working independent

just enter in "price for value" a number

```
$(this).parent().siblings().each(function(){
               $('.output-value2').val((scorenetto).toFixed(2));
            });
```

something is wrong with it, but I am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.output-value2').val((scorenetto).toFixed(2));
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QjwdR/21/

By the way: try to avoid using `$(this)`, instead cache your result in a meanigful variable, e.g.:

```
$(".input-value").keyup(function() {
            var $singlePrice = $(this);
            var value = parseFloat($singlePrice.val());
            ...
});
```

**Caching results makes your code more readable and reduces number of DOM operations.**
See this fiddle for inspiration: http://jsfiddle.net/QjwdR/23/